# Jetbrains IDE shortcuts not working on MacBook

Tags: intellij-idea, phpstorm, webstorm, rubymine, jetbrains-ide

The shortcuts, or at least many of them, does not work for MacBook Air/Pro, probably since the keyboard layout is different from a desktop keyboard.

I know I can change the shortcuts to whatever I want, but maybe there is a way / maybe somebody has made shortcuts that works with MacBook? I am using WebStorm, but hopefully there is a universal Jetbrain IDE shortcut solution?

Comment: Comment with line `CMD`+`-` and
Comment with block comment `CMD`+`SHIFT`+`-`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'MacOSX 10.5+' keymap works on MacBook; what keyboard layout do you have? Shortcuts don't work properly for non-US layouts because of AWT problems - see [IDEA-63779](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-63779)

Comment: Oh, I have Norwegian (probably the same layout as Danish and Swedish, sometimes collectively referred to as Scandinavian layout). Will check out your suggestion...

Comment: Awesome! "Column Selection Mode" shortcut only worked when you first clicked on the Edit menu (at which point you might as well click on the option). I already thought I'd have to post a question to get this solved but I was using MacOSX. With MacOSX 1.5+ it's working now! Thanks!